# Jenkins GitSCM checkout in specific folder

Tags: git, jenkins, plugins, version-control, checkout

I searched a lot, the GitSCM plugin and stackoverflow etc but could not find answer.  I want to checkout Git repository via Jenkins GitSCM plugin into one specific folder say 'MyFolder'.

So if my repository is `xyz.git` then after checkout all files of repository should be in `MyFolder/*` and NOT in `MyFolder/xyz/*`.

To understand more, I want to achieve below (assuming repository is xyz.git) with Jenkins GitSCM plugin.  Below command will checkout files in `MyFolder` excluding root folder `xyz`

```
git clone <REPOSITORY> -- MyFolder
```

and below command will checkout files in xyz folder

```
git clone <REPOSITORY>
```

For reference I am working on below configuration

```
  checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: gitDefaultBranch]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: gitCreds, url: gitProjectUrl]]])
```

Please suggest.
Versions information:

- Jenkins 2.121.1 core
- Pipeline: Declarative 1.3.2
- Pipeline: Groovy 2.55
- Git plugin 3.9.1
- org.jenkins-ci.plugins:scm-api:2.3.0
- org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-scm-step:2.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the  `[[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'MyFolder/']]` in you checkout code.

Something like below:-

```
 checkout([   $class: 'GitSCM',
         branches: [[name: gitDefaultBranch]],
         doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
         extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],
                      [$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                       disableSubmodules: false,
                       parentCredentials: true,
                       recursiveSubmodules: true,
                       reference: '',
                       trackingSubmodules: false],
                      [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                       relativeTargetDir: 'MyFolder/']],
         submoduleCfg: [],
         userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: gitCreds, url: gitProjectUrl]]
       ])
```

Comment: reformatted . Hope I have not messed up your answer.

Comment: This is not very useful to someone that is not as familiar with groovy. An example would be more helpful. The `$class` construct is weird to me, as well as the fact that it looks like the `RelativeTargetDirectory` looks to itself be an argument for `extensions` (?)